# Advice on structuring an social science experiment in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am playing around with Meteor as a framework for building web-deployed economics experiments. I am seeking advice on how to structure the app.

Here is the logic:

1. Users create an account and are put in a queue.
2. Groups of size N are formed from users in the queue.
3. Each group proceeds together through a series of stages.
4. Each stage consists of:
    a. The display of information to and collection of simple input from group members. 
    b. Computing new information based on the inputs of all group members.
5. Groups move from stage to stage together, because the group data from one stage provides information needed in the next stage.
6. When the groups complete the last stage, data relating to their session is saved for analysis.
7. If a user loses their connection, they can rejoin by logging in and resume the state they were in before.

It is much like a multiplayer game, and I know there are many examples of those, so perhaps the answer to my question is just a pointer to a similarly structured and well-developed Meteor game.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a framework for deploying multi-user experiments on Meteor. It basically does everything you asked for and a lot more.

> https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor

We should talk! I'm currently using this for a couple of experiments but it is not well documented yet. However, it is a redesign of https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/TurkServer so all of the important features are there. Also, I'm looking to broaden out from using Amazon Mechanical Turk for subject recruitment, and Meteor makes that easy.

Even if you're not interested in using this, you should check out the source for how people are split into groups and kept segregated. The original idea came from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/8u2LVk8si_s), but I've expanded on it significantly so that it is automagically managed by the smart package instead of having to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I didn't know anyone had yet come so far down this road with Meteor. I do use mTurk sometimes, and I'm looking for a framework that I can do all my development in, whether for in-lab or on-line sessions, and that is multiplatform, hence Meteor. I'll shoot you a PM about talking.